# Publishing an app on the Mac Appstore bundled with the Growl.Framework

Tags: mac-app-store, growl

I have spent hours trying to publish my new Mac OS app to the Mac AppStore. I keep getting an email after publication about a malformed framework:

> Malformed Framework - The framework bundle (XXXX.app/Contents/Frameworks/Growl.framework) must contain a symbolic link 'Growl' -> 'Versions/Current/Growl'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.
>
> Malformed Framework - The framework bundle (XXXX.app/Contents/Frameworks/Growl.framework) must contain a symbolic link 'Resources' -> 'Versions/Current/Resources'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.
>
> Malformed Framework - The framework bundle (XXXX.app/Contents/Frameworks/Growl.framework) contains 'Headers', which should be a symbolic link -> 'Versions/Current/Headers'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.
>
> Malformed Framework - The framework bundle (XXXX.app/Contents/Frameworks/Growl.framework) 'Versions' directory must contain a symbolic link 'Current' resolving to a specific version directory. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.

These errors are pretty self explanatory but I can not find a way as to why this happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the way I was copying the `Growl.Framework` in the `Run Script` phase of my build process in XCode 5. I was using

```
cp -pr /Library/Frameworks/Growl.framework $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$FULL_PRODUCT_NAME/Contents/Frameworks
```

but on Mac OS the `cp` command misses a lot of options to preserve symbolic links and I had to use:

```
cp -R /Library/Frameworks/Growl.framework $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$FULL_PRODUCT_NAME/Contents/Frameworks
```

Then my app moved to the "Waiting for review" state

Comment: i am having the same issue, But i dont have any xcode project, how to use this runscript. i have spendlots of hours on this

Comment: @Swati unfortunately I'm not working on that app anymore so I'm not sure how to solve this but the issue was related to symbolic links so that's what you need to focus on fixing